# Android, TextWatcher event caught before OnItemClickListener event

Tags: android

My text view (of type AutoCompleteTextView) listens to both TextWatcher and OnItemClickListener.

`textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);`

```
    textView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

My objective is this: when a user enters a character the text view will display in the view's drop down list relevant items which contain the entered character (hereby task A). When a user chooses an item from the list I would like to save it (hereby task B).
I perform task A within the scope of afterTextChanged(Editable text) and task B within the scope of onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id).
Task A works fine but when I choose an item from the list (and expect OnItemClick() to perform task B) afterTextChanged() is called (probably because the text has indeed changed) before OnItemClick() causing task A to run again.
Any idea how to prevent this?
Thanks, Rob

Comment: Just to understand the correct order:
You click on the list and afterTextChanged() is called before onItemClick() and is not triggered by a call inside onItemClick()?

Comment: Correct. afterTextChanged() is called before onItemClick() and there is no call inside onItemClick() related to text.

Comment: Btw, I tried with OnItemSelected() as well - with the same result.